# A straightforword method to select columns by position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clarify how can I manage pandas methods to call columns and rows in a Dataframe. An example will clarify my issue

```
dic = {'a': [1, 5, 2, 7], 'b': [6, 8, 4, 2], 'c': [5, 3, 2, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic, index = ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'] )
```

than

```
df = 
   a  b  c
e  1  6  5
f  5  8  3
g  2  4  2
h  7  2  7
```

Now if I want to select column 'a' I just have to type

```
df['a']
```

while if I want to select row 'e' I have to use the ".loc" method

```
df.loc['e']
```

If I don't know the name of the row, but just it's position ( 0 in this case) than I can use the "iloc" method

```
df.iloc[0]
```

What looks like it is missing is a method for calling columns by position and not by name, something that is the "equivalent for columns of the 'iloc' method for rows". The only way I can find to do this is

```
df[df.keys()[0]]
```

is there something like

```
df.ilocColumn[0]
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `:` because first argument is position of selected indexes and second position of columns in function [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

And `:` means all indexes in `DataFrame`:

```
print (df.iloc[:,0])
e    1
f    5
g    2
h    7
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

If need select first index and first column value:

```
print (df.iloc[0,0])
1
```

Solution with [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) work nice if need select index by name and column by position:

```
print (df.ix['e',0])
1
```

Comment: And what about the command

       df.iloc[:][0]

it looks like doing the some job as 

       df.iloc[:, 0]

do we have two different ways to do the some thing or there is any difference between them?